# ngDisabled alternative for link?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-ng-disabled

I have a list on my page with delete button for each element. The button is not `<button>`, but actually is a fontawesome icon with `ng-click` pointing at method of RESTful service:

```
<i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg pull-right" ng-click="deleteQuestion($id)"</i>
```

The element will be removed from view only when Http request will be completed. If user presses the icon too fast multiple times, duplicate requests will be sent and only first  will be successful, others will fail, because entity does not exist. I want to disable button (icon) or do not send duplicate requests. What is the best approach?

I know there is `ngDisabled`, but i can not use it, cause the element is not actually a button, and i also want to block one button. not all at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this -

```
$scope.deleteQuestion(id) {
    $scope.disabled = true;
    $http.get('url')
    .success(data){
        //other logic
        $scope.removed = true;
    }
}
```

And in your markup you can have -

```
<i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg pull-right" ng-show="!removed" ng-disabled="deleted" ng-click="deleteQuestion($id)"</i>
```

> This is the simplest way to do this but certainly not the most **elegant**.

Answer (score 0):

> Try following approach **:**
>
> View :

```
<i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg pull-right" ng-hide="remove" ng-click="deleteQuestion($id)"</i>
```

> Js Controller :

```
$scope.remove = false;
    
$scope.deleteQuestion(id) {
      $scope.remove = true;
      $http.get('url')
         .success(data){
            //other logic
            $scope.remove = false;
          }
}
```